# How to implement Quiz in New Actions Builder

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder, google-assistant

How to Implement Trivia/Quiz - Game in New Actions Builder Console for Google Assistant.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately, the site works best when you have a specific question or problem based on something you've tried that doesn't work. In these cases, if you can show us the code that isn't working, the Intents and Scenes that you've tried, and any errors that you may have gotten - we can probably help. While we can help with some design questions, it is very difficult to answer broad questions unless you've tried something yourself. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You should create an entity type for each available response, for example: optionA, optionB types with default answers like "number one", "letter a", etc, for each one.

Add them to intents like "optionAIntent", "optionBIntent", etc, respectively. These intents must point to a webhook.

Then in your webhook you use "type override" to dinamicaly add the expected answers for each response type for that specific question during the trivia game.

Here's the reference on how to use type overrides on actions builder :
https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhooks#runtime_type_overrides

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, i am trying to follow your steps but somewhere i get stuck. Could you describe your solution a bit more in details?
At the moment i have everything as you said but i do not know how my API result should look like with the override.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @CarlosPinto. If I got your question, follow a snippet code on how to use _TypeOverrrides_ 
conv.session.typeOverrides = [{ name: 'AnswerType', mode: 'TYPE_REPLACE', synonym: { entries: [{ name: 'ANSWER', synonyms: [_.uniq(arrayAnswer)], }]}}];